# Getting null response of resttemplate exchange in a mockito test

Tags: java, mockito

i am trying to write the mock test case for RestServiceImpl class. Below is the code. And i have a test class shown below RestServiceImplTest. When i run the test class it returning null from line restTemplate.exchange(UrlString, HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class)

```
    public class RestServiceImpl 
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

   @Autowired
   public RestServiceImpl(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
      this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
   }

   @Override
   public ResponseEntity<Object> restService(DataRequest dataRequest) throws Exception {
      ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

      HttpEntity<DataRequest> request = new HttpEntity<>(dataRequest, headers);
      try {
         response = restTemplate.exchange(UrlString, HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         throw ex;
      }
      return response;
   }
}
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class RestServiceImplTest {

   private RestServiceImpl restServiceImpl;

   @Mock
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;
   @Mock
   private DataRequest dataRequest;
   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      restServiceImpl = new RestServiceImpl(restTemplate);
      dataRequest = new DataRequest();
   }

   @Test
   public void testRestServiceImplwithSuccess() throws Exception {
      ResponseEntity<Object> resp = new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.OK);
      doReturn(resp).when(restTemplate).exchange(any(URI.class), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class),
            any(Class.class));
      ResponseEntity<Object> mockResp = restServiceImpl.restService(DataRequest);
   }
```

Can anybody tell me where is it going wrong.

Comment: I strongly recommend using [`@RestClientTest`](https://rieckpil.de/testing-your-spring-resttemplate-with-restclienttest/) for such test as you otherwise end up in a mocking hell with a copy of your implementation. If you still want to proceed the mocking-route, consider [Mockito's deep stub feature](https://rieckpil.de/creating-deep-stubs-with-mockito-to-chain-method-stubbing/) to get the stubbing setup right.

Comment: What is the type of `UrlString` in `RestServiceImpl`?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly this is happening because your **doReturn** is not being used due to the parameters not being met (your **any()** s).